# Self-Contained Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

### My output:

### The next node is: This

Here I get next node as `This`... The actual next node should be `World`.
If I change my return value of Next() as,

```
return nextnode;
```

Then it prints,

> The next node is: Hello

I am not able to print `World` as next node.

I need help doing this... Here is my code,

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element(const std::string& str):   data(str), next(nullptr)
    {

    }

    void Append(const Element& elem)
    {
        Element *tail = this;
        //printf("%s\n", tail->data.c_str());
        while (tail->next)
            tail = tail->next;
        tail->next = new Element(elem.data);
    }

    void Print(int n)
    {       
        if(n==1)
        {           
            printf("The next node is: %s\n", Next()->data.c_str());         
        }
    }   

    Element *Next()
    {
        Element *nextnode = this;
        if(nextnode->next)
            return nextnode->next;

        return NULL;
    }

private:    
    string data;
    Element *next;  
};

void main()
{
    // construct a list
    Element *root = new Element("Hello");

    root->Append(Element("World"));
    root->Append(Element("This"));
    root->Append(Element("Is"));
    root->Append(Element("a"));
    root->Append(Element("Linked"));
    root->Append(Element("List"));      
    root->Next()->Print(1);//It prints 'World' if I change code here as root->Print(1);
                                // But I dont want to change here...
}
```

Comment: This is doing *exactly* what you're telling it to. You're essentially telling it to print `root->Next()->Next()->data.c_str()`. So stare at that a minute and then ask yourself what is the 3rd word in your list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is expected to print "This"
Because you call

```
root->Next()->Print(1);
```

And print is defined to print `Next()->data.c_str()`, by the way it's unsafe because Next() may be NULL.

So your list is like "Hello" -> "World" -> "This" where `root` is "Hello", `root->Next` is "World", and of course it will print "This" in your case

What you prabaly meant is to have the `Print()` method to print the current value, not the next node's value. So change it to

```
printf("The next node is: %s\n", data.c_str());
```

And use standard streams for printing (`std::cout`) since it's c++

Answer (score 2):

Your design is kind of strange. It is a valid choice to only print the next node, but that usually involves the creation of a dummy root node, because the `"Hello"` in node `root` is never accessable. That is also what is causing this strange behavior:

```
auto n = root->Next(); // Now we are at World
n->Print(1); // We print World->Next, so This
```

You could change your `Print` routine to not use the next, but the current node.